# SharePoint 2013 Calendar Overlays - changing the color label

Tags: css, sharepoint-2013

We are trying to change the colors of our calendar overlays in SharePoint 2013.  I have been able to successfully modify the css in order to change the actual color, but the color names remain the original (Dark Teal, Olive Green etc.)

I have found many posts describing how to change the color but none on where to rename the colors in the drop down selector.  I'm guessing this information is stored in a file somewhere but I've been unable to locate it in the corev15.css or within the aggregationcustomization.aspx page itself.

Does anybody know where or how I might find and modify these labels?

Thanks,

Comment: inspect from your browser on that element, and trying changing css property right in browser and find which elements actually happens color change...and find.

Comment: I was able to inspect directly in the browser and see the html elements for the names and modify them.  However, they are not listed when I open the aspx page itself in an editor.I assume that they are getting pulled into the page dynamically from another location

Answer (score 1):

Customize the SharePoint Calendar Colors :
you can review this https://davidlozzi.com/2012/06/20/customize-the-sharepoint-calendar-colors/

Comment: Thanks, this explains how to change the colors but it does not explain how to change the color names.  The colors have already been updated in our environment, but the names for the colors within the calendar overlays area have not.  So for example, we have changed the colors for element .ms-acal-color4 to light blue, but the drop down when choosing the light blue color is still labeled as 'Dark Green'